# WinForm InitializeComponent Performance

Tags: winforms, performance

I have a WinForm application that has 700 individual items (combo boxes, grids, text boxes, etc.). There are twelve tabs with a grid on each tab and then text boxes for data entry. All of the data needs to be on this form. I've suggested splitting into individual components and the owner stating that this is what is wanted.

With no database calls, just loading the form, takes 17 seconds. Is there a way to improve the load time?

Comment: Do you really have to have such enormous number of Controls? I doubt that anyone could comprehend that... I believe redesign the UI is an answer to your question :(

Answer (score 1):

Delay-Loading.

Add your first tab, then add 11 blank TabPages (each with the proper name).  The TabControl will look the same.

Then on each firing of OnAppIdle, replace one blank TabPage with the real one.

You will additionally need to handle OnTabPageSelected in case the user picks a tab you haven't yet delay loaded.

--

I have code to show when I get back to a computer with my source.